# Выборка из бд с помощью php и js

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, mysqli

Есть php код

```
    $myArray  = array();
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM mydb.rooms";
    $rs =$conn->query($strSQL);
    while($row = $rs->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
    {
    $MyArray[] = $row;
    }
    echo( json_encode(['records'=>($MyArray)]));
```

Есть сontroller.js

```
.factory('playlistService',function($http)
{
    var playlists = [{idr:1, namer:"Standart"}];

    return {
        playlists:playlists
    }

});
```

Как добавить данные из php в playlists

Comment: аяксом "просить" у пхп результата. Или выводить результат на страницу в теги в какие - то , и жской циклом бегать по ним.

Comment: Как реализовать аяксом?Только вникаю. Не могли бы вы подсказать что и где писать?